# Is it possible to not use smbpasswd to share samba home folders in linux?

Tags: linux, samba, cifs

I have a linux (Ubuntu) server with a few users on it that I allow their home folders to be accessed via smb.

However, in order for them to access the folder, I need to use smbpasswd -a username

Why is that? On authentication, shouldn't it just refer to their actual username and password they use to ssh into the server?

My config:

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    server string = Samba Server %v
    netbios name = myserver
    security = user
    map to guest = bad user
    name resolve order = bcast host
    dns proxy = no
    wins support = yes
    local master = yes
    preferred master = yes
    server min protocol = SMB2_10
    client max protocol = SMB3
    client min protocol = SMB2_10
    encrypt passwords = true

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S
```

Comment: Your question is answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/153893/samba-and-user-acount-passwords

Comment: That's right. Thank you!